# How can I access DOM elements in Electron Js App?

Tags: javascript, html, electron, addeventlistener

I am creating a Electron JS webapp with multiple pages for a project.
So far I have created a new page in a different folder for my To Do list feature.

I am running into a problem because when I enter a new task in the form It does not appear when I click submit.

Here is what is supposed to look like after I click Add New Task.
[image]

Here is what my task list looks like when I try to add a new task.
[image]

Here is my script.js file and html file. I appreciate any help you can give me!

SCRIPT.JS

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    // Uses ids that was created in html 
    const form = document.querySelector("#new-task-form");
    const input = document.querySelector("#new-task-input");
    const list_el = document.querySelector("#tasks");

    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();// stop the page from refreshing after submitting task

        const task = input.value;
        // Prevent user from submitting a empty task
        if (!task) {
            alert("Please enter out the task!");
        }
            else {
                console.log("Success");
                return;
            }
        
        // Getting task elements to display on page by creating DOM nodes
        const task_el = document.createElement("div");
        task_el.classList.add("task");
        
        const task_content_el = document.createElement("div");
        task_content_el.classList.add("content");
        // Set inner value to task 
        task_actions_el.innerText = task;

        task_content_el.appendChild(task_content_el);
        task_content_el.appendChild(task_el);

        })
    })
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Task List</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<div class="datetime">
  <div class="time"></div>
  <div class="date"></div>
</div>
<body>
  
    <header>
        <h1>Task List</h1>
        <form id="new-task-form">
            <input 
                type="text" 
                name="new-task-input" 
                id="new-task-input" 
                placeholder="What do you have planned?" />
            <input 
                type="submit"
                id="new-task-submit" 
                value="Add task" />
        </form>
    </header>
    <main>
    
        <section class="task-list">
            <h2>Tasks</h2>

            <div id="tasks">

                <!-- <div class="task">
                    <div class="content">
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            class="text" 
                            value="A new task"
                            readonly>
                    </div>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                        <button class="delete">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>  -->

            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

    <script src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear like you are adding the task_content_el that you create to your tasks div.

You are missing a line at the end to append the created elements to an element in your html.

```
list_el.appendChild(task_content_el);
```